# C# PDF reader only works with the pdf files in the debug folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf

I have an issue with an C# application. I am trying to read some PDF files and load the data into a database.
The application make works good only when the PDF files are in a specific folder. the folder is the debug folder of the project.

I need to load the PDF files from any folder.

```
public string LecturaPDF(string nombreArchivo)
        {
            PdfReader lectorPDF = new PdfReader(nombreArchivo);
            string TextoPuro = string.Empty;
            string[] TextoDividido;
            string TextoFinal = string.Empty;

            for (int a = 1; a <= lectorPDF.NumberOfPages; a++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy pdfParser = 
                    new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                TextoPuro = TextoPuro + PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(lectorPDF, a, pdfParser);
            }
            lectorPDF.Close();

            TextoDividido = TextoPuro.Split('\n');

            for (int b = 0; b < TextoDividido.Count(); b++)
            {
                if (TextoDividido[b].First()== '7')
                {
                    TextoFinal = TextoFinal + TextoDividido[b] + ";";
                }
            }
            return ';' + TextoFinal;
        }
```

the error occur in this line **PdfReader lectorPDF = new PdfReader(nombreArchivo);**
the error say:

> C:\user\me\MyDocuments\Projects\Project1\bin\debug\test.pdf not found
>   as file or resource

With this function I open a dialog box to select the file and call the function to read the pdf file:

```
private void cmdProcesar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (dialogoArchivo.ShowDialog().Value)
                    {
                        for (int a = 0; a < dialogoArchivo.FileNames.Count(); a++)
                        {
                            lblEstado.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)(() => lblEstado.Content =
                                 "Procesando archivos contra Billing..."));

                            archivo.InsercionArchivo(dialogoArchivo.SafeFileNames[a], G_Fecha,
                                   archivo.LecturaPDF(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dialogoArchivo.SafeFileNames[a])),
                                   Convert.ToDouble(txtTarifa.Text),
                                   conexion.ConexionOracle);
                        }
}
```

This is my first time with C# and I don't know why only works wwhen I read the files from the project debug folder

Any advice will appreciated

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

```
private void cmdProcesar_Automatico(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {
            string carpeta = "C:\\temp";
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(carpeta);
            FileInfo[] documentos = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf");
            txtTarifa.Text = "1.48";
            foreach (FileInfo archivopdf in documentos)
            {
                lblEstado.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)(() => lblEstado.Content =
                                "Procesando archivos contra Billing..."));

                archivo.InsercionArchivo(archivopdf.Name, G_Fecha,
                       archivo.LecturaPDF(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(archivopdf.Name)),
                       Convert.ToDouble(txtTarifa.Text),
                       conexion.ConexionOracle);

            }
        }
```

I change the function to automatically read all the file in a specific folder and process every file.

But I get the same error:

> C:\user\me\MyDocuments\Projects\Project1\bin\debug\test.pdf not found
>   as file or resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `OpenFileDialog.SafeFileNames` (emphasis mine):

> Gets an array of file names and extensions for all the selected files in the dialog box. **The file names do not include the path.**

As it doesn't contain the path, the *current* path will be used which when you're running in the debugger will be bin\debug by default.

If you know the directory that the file should be chosen from you could add it to the file name (using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) but if you would prefer the full path you can use the `FileNames` property which according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (again, emphasis mine):

> Each file name includes **both the file path and the extension**. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty array.

In your context you'd need to change this line:

```
archivo.LecturaPDF(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dialogoArchivo.SafeFileNames[a])),
```

to

```
archivo.LecturaPDF(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dialogoArchivo.FileNames[a])),
```

**EDIT**

To answer the question in your edit - you are getting `FileInfo` objects for all `pdf` files in `C:\temp` but you are then using `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(archivopdf.Name)` to get the file path to pass to `archivo.LecturaPDF`. The documentation for [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx) states (emphasis mine again):

> This method uses current directory and current volume information to fully qualify path. **If you specify a file name only in path, GetFullPath returns the fully qualified path of the *current* directory.**

Imagine that you have a `FileInfo` for the file `c:\temp\example.pdf`. When you call `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(archivopdf.Name)` on that `FileInfo` you are essentially calling `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("example.pdf")`. This will give the file name of `example.pdf` but it will use the *current* path for the path which in your case is `C:\user\me\MyDocuments\Projects\Project1\bin\debug\` (the path your executable is running from).

This results in a fully qualified file name of `C:\user\me\MyDocuments\Projects\Project1\bin\debug\example.pdf` which isn't what you want and presumably doesn't exist.

As you already have a `FileInfo` object the solution is straightforward - you can use the [`FullName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) directly without the need to call `GetFullPath`. The `FullName` property will give you the correct fully qualified name of `c:\temp\example.pdf`.

Your code should therefore read:

```
 archivo.InsercionArchivo(archivopdf.Name, G_Fecha,
                   archivo.LecturaPDF(archivopdf.FullName),
                   Convert.ToDouble(txtTarifa.Text),
                   conexion.ConexionOracle);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late. Thanks.

Comment: I have to change the application and now I need to process all the files from a specific folder I change the function but I get the same error.

Comment: @joseleg - I've updated my answer based on your edit. I hope that helps?